# Relative positioning of an :after point

Tags: html, css, html-lists, pseudo-element

I have created a css 'arrow' using borders and the pseudo :after element. Here is the live example (you need to hover over 'work' to see it in action. http://citizenfilms.co.uk/beta/

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to get this point to always be in relation to the parent item i.e 'Work'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but it looks like you will need another wrapper inside of '.brick-overlay' and apply the ::after pseudo element to that with relative positioning:

`<div class="brick-overlay colour-array">`
   `<div class="new-wrapper">`...
   `</div>`
`</div>`

Comment: Hi, sorry I think we are looking at two different parts. I'm referring to the arrow on the green sub-menu, which appears when hovering over 'Work'. I want this to position itself below 'Work' (parent element), but cannot use static figures in the css as it won't be responsive. Any ideas?